# Flutter: Countdown timer that displays minutes and seconds

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have created a countdown timer that will countdown from a user inputted duration, in minutes.

The countdown timer technically works, but only the minutes are being shown counting down.  The seconds remain at :00 the entire time.

How can I get the seconds to also display as part of the countdown timer?

Here is the relevant code, excerpted from a longer file.  I can include more if needed.

The individual pieces of code are broken down as follows:

First, I have a class that actually displays the timer text and allows it to be styled:

```
class Countdown extends AnimatedWidget {
  Countdown({ Key key, this.animation }) : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
  Animation<int> animation;

  @override

  build(BuildContext context){

    Duration clockTimer = Duration(seconds: animation.value*60);

    String timerText = '${clockTimer.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString()}:${(clockTimer.inSeconds.remainder(60) % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';

    return Text(
      "$timerText",
      style: TextStyle(         
        fontSize: 110,
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

I have an animation controller as follows:

```
AnimationController _controller;

  @override

  void dispose(){
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    @override

      _controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(minutes: gameData.levelClock)  // gameData.levelClock is a user entered number elsewhere in the applciation
      );


  }
```

And finally here is the part of the code that calls the Countdown widget:

```
Countdown(
     animation: StepTween(
     begin: gameData.levelClock,   // THIS IS A USER ENTERED NUMBER 
     end: 0,
   ).animate(_controller),
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem is that when you create the `CountDown` widget you set begin to a double value which is the value in minutes for your timer(for this example say the value is 5). As the animation continues it will count down from `begin` to `end`(0 in this case). Over 5 minutes it will animate from 5 to 0.

You then use the value and convert it to seconds but since the value of the animation is between 0 and 5 it will always give you 5:00, 4:00, 3:00, 2:00, 1:00 or 0:00.

The solution would be to change your code to

```dart
Countdown(
     animation: StepTween(
     begin: gameData.levelClock * 60, // convert to seconds here
     end: 0,
   ).animate(_controller),
)
```

and then in your countdown widget change the `Duration` to

```dart
Duration clockTimer = Duration(seconds: animation.value);
```

You can find a working example on DartPad [here](https://dartpad.dev/2558d114b8437f28df9fb8b57a123c7a)

Comment: is there a way if want to make the countdown start again, by a click of a button?

Comment: @ali Yes, simply call `_controller.reset() ` to reset the animation controller to its initial values and then call `_controller.forward()` to start the animation again

Answer (score 18):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Your duration of AnimationController need to use seconds 
code snippet

```
_controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(
            seconds:
                levelClock) // gameData.levelClock is a user entered number elsewhere in the applciation
        );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _counter = 0;
  AnimationController _controller;
  int levelClock = 180;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(
            seconds:
                levelClock) // gameData.levelClock is a user entered number elsewhere in the applciation
        );

    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Countdown(
              animation: StepTween(
                begin: levelClock, // THIS IS A USER ENTERED NUMBER
                end: 0,
              ).animate(_controller),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Countdown extends AnimatedWidget {
  Countdown({Key key, this.animation}) : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
  Animation<int> animation;

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    Duration clockTimer = Duration(seconds: animation.value);

    String timerText =
        '${clockTimer.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString()}:${clockTimer.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';

    print('animation.value  ${animation.value} ');
    print('inMinutes ${clockTimer.inMinutes.toString()}');
    print('inSeconds ${clockTimer.inSeconds.toString()}');
    print('inSeconds.remainder ${clockTimer.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString()}');

    return Text(
      "$timerText",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 110,
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how to use text size with this

Comment: "vsync: this" displaying error, not able to compile.

Comment: @Kamlesh, I have tested full again. it works fine. did you forget to use TickerProviderStateMixin => State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin